# Using CoreText To Set Color of NSAttributedString in iOS 6 Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, core-text, nsattributedstring

I have the following code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_textView.text];
NSRange totalRange = NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString length]);
[attributedString addAttribute:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName
                         value:(id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor
                         range:totalRange];
```

Which, when run on iOS 6 always causes the string to show up as red.

What is interesting is that CoreText works for specifying font, like so:

```
[attributedString addAttribute:(id)kCTFontAttributeName
                         value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]
                         range:specialFontRange];
```

Setting color works fine when done this way:

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                         value:[UIColor yellowColor]
                         range:totalRange];
```

But I must use CoreText for compatibility reasons. Any ideas on how to use CoreText to specify colors in iOS 6?

Answer (score 0):

it really depends on how you are drawing the text.  If you are using `-(void)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect;` or `-(void)drawAtPoint:(CGPoint)point;` (only available in iOS6 or later) then you must use the constants specified in the [constants section of NSAttributedString Additions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000167-BAJJCCFC). For example, to set the text color, you must use the key `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`.

If you are using Core Graphics to do the drawing, then you need to stick to the constants specified in [Core Text String Attributes Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/reference/CoreText_StringAttributes_Ref/Reference/reference.html).